# How can I properly run asynchronous operations sequentially in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, async-await

I am saving a photo. The user takes a photo or selects a photo from the gallery and a request is sent to the service and saved to the locale. Of course, these are done asynchronously and after the saving process, he has to navigate back to the profile page again. I used async await to manage these operations respectively because sometimes the image was navigated directly without being saved, which caused the image not to appear. So I followed a path like this

**Save Image To Datastore**

```
 private fun saveUserImgToDataStore(
        userAvatar: String,
        navHostController: NavHostController,
        route: String
    ) {

        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                dataStore.putPreference(PreferenceDataStoreConstants.USER_IMG, userAvatar)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("error", e.toString())
                navHostController.navigate(route)
            }
        }
    }
```

**Save Photo To Service**

```
private fun saveProfilePhoto(encodedImg: String?) {


    if (!encodedImg.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        val _encodedImg = "data:image/png;base64,$encodedImg"
        saveProfilePhotoUseCase.invoke(SaveProfilePhotoRequestModel(_encodedImg))
            .onEach { result ->
                println("1")
                when (result) {
                    is Resource.Success -> {
                        _state.update {
                            it.copy(
                                isLoadingSavePhoto = false,
                                responseSavePhoto = result.data,
                                isError = result.data?.isError == 1
                            )
                        }

                    }
                    is Resource.Loading -> {
                        _state.update {
                            it.copy(
                                isLoadingSavePhoto = true
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    is Resource.Error -> {
                        _state.update {
                            it.copy(
                                error = !result.message.isNullOrEmpty(),
                                isLoadingSavePhoto = false
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }
}
```

**Save Image And Navigate**

```
 fun saveImageAndNavigate(
        encodedImg: String?,
        capturedImageUri: String,
        navHostController: NavHostController,
        route: String
    ){

        viewModelScope.launch {
            val savePhotoToService = async { saveProfilePhoto(encodedImg) }
            val savePhotoToLocale = async { saveUserImgToDataStore(capturedImageUri, navHostController, route) }
            val navigate = async { navigate(navHostController, route) }

            savePhotoToService.await()
            savePhotoToLocale.await()
            navigate.await()
        }
    }
```

**Navigate**

```
 private fun navigate(navHostController: NavHostController, route: String) {

        viewModelScope.launch {
            navHostController.navigate(route)
            println("3")
        }

    }
```

But even though I used async await it didn't work. As you can see, I showed their order on the screen with println(), and although it should normally be written in the order of 1 2 3, it is written out of order like 1 3 2. How can I make them wait for each other?

Comment: If you want to be sure it's executed in order 1-2-3. then call `await` directly after starting the task, instead of after starting all 3. But that would also make the whole async thing pointless.

Comment: Also, you should read up on the basics of coroutines. The way you are using `launch` and `async` is wrong. Don't just launch in randomly available scopes, make your functions `suspend` and nest those coroutines properly.

Comment: I read the documentation but I couldn't do it. Can you give an example how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code and your question title have the same confusion. Asynchronous and sequential are opposites. You can’t do both simultaneously! Theoretically you could start asynchronous work and then wait for it to finish synchronously, but this would be pointless.

When you launch a coroutine, the coroutine is run asynchronously from the perspective of the code that called it.

Suspend functions are *synchronous* functions with the ability to run their long-running code on appropriate threads different than the code that called the function.

Since you want sequential behavior, you should be defining synchronous suspend functions, not asynchronous functions (the ones firing off other coroutines with `launch` calls), and you shouldn’t be wrapping your function calls in `async` blocks that make them doubly asynchronous.

For example, this function should be rewritten as follows:

```
private suspend fun saveUserImgToDataStore(
        userAvatar: String,
        navHostController: NavHostController,
        route: String
) {
    try {
        dataStore.putPreference(PreferenceDataStoreConstants.USER_IMG, userAvatar)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
         Log.e("error", e.toString())
         navHostController.navigate(route)
    }
}
```

Your second function is baffling because I don’t see how it can possibly make sense to consume a whole flow as part of the process of saving a single photo. So that one needs some design work.

The navigate function doesn’t do anything blocking or suspending so it can be just a regular function that doesn’t launch a coroutine to do its work.

But after you finish fixing your theee functions to be synchronous, then your code that calls them can simply call them in sequence:

```
fun saveImageAndNavigate(
    encodedImg: String?,
    capturedImageUri: String,
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    route: String
){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        saveProfilePhoto(encodedImg)
        saveUserImgToDataStore(capturedImageUri, navHostController, route)
        navigate(navHostController, route)
    }
}
```

Comment: to be honest I'm confused too because multiple async operations confuse me but I understand your explanation. I guess I need to practice about async operations. Thanks for your response.